# Angular/YouTube API - refused to display: in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin

Tags: angular, api, youtube

I have seen lots of posts concerning this issue but all I've seen is embedded videos which I believe is not my case. I have a URL that is supposed to give me a video based on user's input so a trailer can be watched, but the error message appears in the console:

> Refused to display 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=robocop&topicId=%2Fm%2F02vxn&key=AIzaSyB42WhSTkS6_0uUPX6EuGakkGz4RHXnlIc' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Here is the code:

Component:

```
safeUrl: SafeResourceUrl
  
  constructor(private movieService: MoviesService, private fb: FormBuilder,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    
this.safeUrl =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl
("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=robocop&topicId=%2Fm%2F02vxn&key=AIzaSyB42WhSTkS6_0uUPX6EuGakkGz4RHXnlIc");
  //this is a static URL to provide the robocop movie trailer
```

HTML:

```
 <iframe [class.thumbnail]="thumbnail" [src]="safeUrl" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen
  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I make this work? Pasting the URL on the browser I get a json like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/cDGghZKnwX2aAUA7AHR1yBLd91k\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "regionCode": "PT",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/YWtWaXHndgHpHajPoRfWHslrqXc\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Z931XZ2wfpE"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-11-13T15:46:31.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCuwxAIqBcP-9W9CNYAAg7KA",
    "title": "RoboCop (1987) - First Mission (1080p) FULL HD",
    "description": "For more RoboCop Videos - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLainponqoUGNp-P_Jg2359ahWVOJNdKpd.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Z931XZ2wfpE/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Z931XZ2wfpE/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Z931XZ2wfpE/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "RED Lion Movie Shorts",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the url that you're trying to hit gives a JSON response which has an `items` property. Each item there has a `vidoeId` which is something you might be interested in to display them as embedded videos in a list.

How about requesting for the data using HttpClient and then using `safeUrl` as `pipe`.

Here's what the component would look like in that case:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  results$: Observable<Array<any>>;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.results$ = this.http.get(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=robocop&topicId=%2Fm%2F02vxn&key=AIzaSyB42WhSTkS6_0uUPX6EuGakkGz4RHXnlIc"
    ).pipe(
      map(res => res.items),
      map((items: Array<any>) => {
        return items.map(item => ({
          title: item.snippet.title,
          vidoeUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${item.id.videoId}`,
        }))
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And then you'd also create a `pipe` to sanitize the url:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
  name: "safeUrl"
})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(url: string, args?: any): SafeResourceUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

You'd finally iterate through the results list in the tempate:

```
<ul *ngIf="results$ | async as results; else elseBlock">
  <li *ngFor="let item of results">
    <iframe 
      [class.thumbnail]="thumbnail" 
      [src]="vidoeUrl | safeUrl" 
      width="560"
      height="315" 
      frameborder="0" 
      webkitallowfullscreen
      mozallowfullscreen 
      allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
  </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #elseBlock>
  Something went wrong
</ng-template>
```

**PS:** Your `id` is private so you shouldn't be sharing it in questions here on StackOverflow. As of now, you'd just see Something went wrong as I'm getting an Unauthorized Error. But it should work just fine for you.

> Here's a [**Working Sample Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-youtube-video-list?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: great answer and explanation, thank you very much (i forgot to hide my key, thanks for pointing that one as well) cheers!

Comment: Hello @SiddAjmera, there is a problem, even with my key I get the reproduction error on youtube screen I thought it was this misspelling `vidoeId: item.id.videoId,` instead of `videoID` (fixed), but its not. I removed my addBlocker but the video isnt showing, do you know whats wrong?

Comment: @Mellville, my bad. The url should be `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${item.id.videoId}` and not `?v=videoId`. I've updated the StackBlitz and it's working now. Please have a look. And sorry about that :) I've updated the answer as well.

Comment: thanks for your attention, now it's really working and the stackblitz example can be really usefull for other people /though its my API key :p) Cheers!